# How to differentiate different groups in bar plot by using R-ggplot2 except using fill-in colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

```
set.seed(1221)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS[1:12], 3), 
                 outcome = c(runif(12, 1, 5), runif(12, 5, 10), runif(12, 5, 8) ), 
                 trt = rep(c("H", "M", "L"), each=12) )

ggplot(df, aes(x=trt, y=outcome, fill=group) ) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

[image]

The code is a simple example that we might have many groups (12 groups in this case).

Right now if we only use color to differentiate different groups, it is not really good, since many color would be close when there are too many groups. Even by changing color palette, I do not think 12 very different colors can be generated and visualization effect is not good.

I think by combining at least two aesthetic property (color and something else), the differentiation might be good. For example, 6 different colors and 2 different something will make 12 groups.

However, I have no idea which aesthetic property except fill-in colors are useful to differentiate groups. I have tried line color and line type, but I do not think they are good.

Any suggestion or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you could check [Color Brewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=qualitative&scheme=Paired&n=12) to build a categorical color palette

Answer (score 3):

Even sticking with fill colours, the differentiation can be improved if you do a couple of things:

- Use a colour palette that's designed to differentiate qualitatively between groups, rather than following a sequential order. The brewer palettes in ggplot are good for this, particularly the "qualitative" ones, although they have upper limits on the number of groups they will accept.
- Adding a border around each group's rectangle

These minor changes do improve things relative to your original plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=trt, y=outcome, fill=group) ) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", colour = 'black') +
    # Note: had to use palette = 3 here as palette's 1 and 2 can't be
    #   used for 12 groups
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 3)
```

[image]